# Mongo incrementing ID problems

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to make incrementing id in User. I tried two ways but in both, I am getting errors.

a)
Model

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: {
    type: Number,
    unique: true
  },  ....
```

Controller

```
const user = new User({
    profile: {
      _id: core.getNextSequenceValue('userid'),
      firstname: req.body.firstname,
      lastname: req.body.lastname,
      location: req.body.location,....
```

Error i am getting

```
mongoose: Cannot specify a custom index on `_id` for model name "User", MongoDB does not allow overwriting the default `_id` index. See
```

b)
Model

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id: {
    type: Number,
    unique: true
  },  ....
```

Controller

```
const user = new User({
id: core.getNextSequenceValue('userid'),
    profile: {
      firstname: req.body.firstname,
      lastname: req.body.lastname,
      location: req.body.location,....
```

The error I am getting

```
 Error: Failed to serialize user into session
```

Is there any way how can I set _id to custom number (from 1 to ...) without downgrade? Or I need to create new custom id like `idx`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

_id field is really special in mongodb. This is your primary key there is no way you can have a document without it. Even you can not modify _id field for you collection.

But you can create a document with your own _id. So if you want you can do `db.users.insert({"_id":"1","User_Name":"avbd"})`

and remember that _id means user_id and also _id should be unique

Comment: Just keep in mind that the type for __id is an ObjectId https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/schema.html#schema-objectid-js